# saving textarea values in hashmap for each toggle button javafx

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, toggle

When I click on the toggle button and input text and then press the same toggle button - (on/off) is saves the textarea text in hashmap with button id but for example when I press on toggle button and add text to the textarea and press other toggle button instead of pressing the same, the value is not added to hashmap and textarea text is lost.

here is my code, please advice

```
Node componentsPane;
int x = 14, y = 0;
ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
Integer id = 1;
String temp;
String tempmessageText = null;

public void initialize() throws SQLException {

    componentsPane = splitPane.getItems().get(1);

    final Statement stmt = null;
    String m = "";

    final String query = "select username from chatuser ";
    final Connection conn = null;

    final Connection _connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://IP/postgres", "postgres",
            "password");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    final PreparedStatement _stmt = _connection.prepareStatement(query);
    final ResultSet res = _stmt.executeQuery();
    while (res.next()) {
        m = res.getString("username");
        final ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton();
        btn.setLayoutX(x);
        btn.setLayoutY(y + 180);
        btn.setText(m);
        btn.setId(id.toString());
        btn.setToggleGroup(group);
        splitPaneLeft.getChildren().add(btn);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(btn.getId());

                if (btn.isSelected()) {

                    temp = btn.getId();
                    System.out.println("yes");

                    splitPane.getItems().remove(componentsPane);

                    splitPane.getItems().add(1, componentsPane);

                    smsBox.setText(hmap.get(Integer.parseInt(temp)));

                    Main.getPrimaryStage().setMaxWidth(840);
                    Main.getPrimaryStage().setWidth(810);
                    Main.getPrimaryStage().setMinWidth(400);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("no");

                    splitPane.getItems().remove(componentsPane);

                    Main.getPrimaryStage().setResizable(false);
                    Main.getPrimaryStage().setMaxWidth(400);
                    System.out.println(smsBox.getText());
                    hmap.put(Integer.parseInt(btn.getId()), smsBox.getText());
                }

            }
        });
        y += 35;
        id++;

    }

}

boolean k;

@FXML
private void func() {
    System.out.println(group.getSelectedToggle());

    if (!group.getSelectedToggle().equals(null)) {

        splitPane.getItems().add(1, componentsPane);
        splitPane.setDividerPosition(1, 0.1);

        Main.getPrimaryStage().setMaxWidth(840);
        Main.getPrimaryStage().setWidth(810);
        Main.getPrimaryStage().setMinWidth(400);

    }

    else {
        System.out.println("false");
        System.out.println(splitPane.getItems());

        System.out.println(Main.getPrimaryStage().getHeight());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onAction` is not triggered for `ToggleButton`s that are unselected when another `Toggle` in the same group gets selected.

Furthermore storing the data in a `Map` seems unnecessary. You create one `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` per button, never modify the `id` of the buttons and only write to the key that corresponds to the button's id. A field would do the same trick.

However I recommend doing by adding a `ChangeListener` to the `ToggleGroup` instead, which allows you to get the `Toggle` that is unselected and the `Toggle` that is selected in a single event. Furthermore adding the id as `userData` allows you to keep the type instead of converting to string and parsing from string...

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    VBox root = new VBox(textArea);

    int id = 0;

    Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    for (String m : strings) {
        ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton(m);
        btn.setUserData(id++);
        btn.setToggleGroup(group);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
    }

    // listen to selection of a different toggle to store data for the old toggle /
    // display stored data for the new toggle
    group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        textArea.setEditable(newValue != null);
        if (oldValue != null) {
            data.put((Integer) oldValue.getUserData(), textArea.getText());
        }
        if (newValue != null) {
            textArea.setText(data.get(newValue.getUserData()));
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```